# Why is UITableViewCell showing wrong data after scrolling the available cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a Download manager for iOS but the issue is when the cells are more than they can fit into the screen after I scroll the screen it starts to give wrong data for **example**:

- a finished/paused/on going download at the beginning of the table view ***after scroll*** it may get displayed at the first visible row or last

here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("downloadCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RCHDownloadAddictTableViewCell

    updateCell(cell, forRowAt: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func updateCell(cell: RCHDownloadAddictTableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let arrayInfo = downloadingArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellProgressView.setProgress((arrayInfo.downloadProgress)!, animated: true)
    cell.cellFileName.text = arrayInfo.fileName
    cell.cellDownloadSpeed.text = String(format: "%.1fMB", (arrayInfo.downloadSize / 1000000))
    cell.cellBlock = {

        if (arrayInfo.downloadTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskState.Running) {
            arrayInfo.downloadTask.suspend()
            cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "resume.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else if (arrayInfo.downloadTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskState.Suspended) {
            arrayInfo.downloadTask.suspend()
            cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "resume.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }

    if (arrayInfo.didFinishDownload == true) {
        cell.cellButton.hidden = true
        cell.cellFinishIndicator.text = "Finished."
        cell.cellProgressView.hidden = true
        cell.cellFinishIndicator.hidden = false
    } else {
        cell.cellButton.hidden = false
        cell.cellProgressView.hidden = false
        cell.cellFinishIndicator.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Update: See this video and focus on the first cell
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_PnAS5lb7s&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Because you haven't implemented `else` block before returning cell

Comment: @arturdev how is that mate ? the example I gave isn't the only thing is happening even on going download of the first cell can display in a wrong row after scrolling

Comment: cells are reused, so if you don't clear a cell of it's previously held information before reusing it then information could be appearing in the wrong places in your tableView.

Comment: @user6190457 see Pramod's answer. :)

Comment: @arturdev I did that and still the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You have used `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` for generate cell. By that method cell is reuse so,system use last generated cell. 
For solve this problem you have to implemented else part like

```
cell.cellBlock = {

    if (arrayInfo.downloadTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskState.Running) {
        arrayInfo.downloadTask.suspend()
        cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "resume.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else if (arrayInfo.downloadTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskState.Suspended) {
        arrayInfo.downloadTask.suspend()
        cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "resume.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else{
        <Write default code here>
    }
}

if (arrayInfo.didFinishDownload == true) {
    cell.cellButton.hidden = true
    cell.cellFinishIndicator.text = "Finished."
    cell.cellProgressView.hidden = true
    cell.cellFinishIndicator.hidden = false
} else {
    cell.cellButton.hidden = false
    cell.cellFinishIndicator.text = "Your text."
    cell.cellProgressView.hidden = false
    cell.cellFinishIndicator.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: it sort of worked. but pause button is still not taking its correct place

Comment: @Raffi you have to manage switch case like if-else condition. You don't have set image of cellButton in default case.

Comment: @Raffi see the else block of 'cell.cellBlock' block

Answer (score 2):

Table view cells are reused via reuse queue.  If you see let say 7 cells on screen at once, and when you scroll down (more finger up), then the cell that was moved out of bounds of the top edge, will be passed from the reused queue to show up on the bottom edge again. This cell is an initialised instance, furthermore you have set some concrete values for the public properties on that cell instance.
It's an object that visually disappears but is still in memory and then it reappears. What you need to do is **clean it up between the moment it disappears and when it reppaears.**

The correct place and way to do this is this:

1) Visuals i.e. stuff related to UIView properties like `.hidden`, `.alpha` or `.backgroundColor` or selection state should be reset to desired default state inside the `prepareForReuse` overridden method inside your custom cell.Don't forget to call super.

2) For content related stuff like download progress I recommend to implement a **custom public** `reset` **method** on the cell, inside the method do whatever you want that doesn't fall into `prepareForReuse` group, and call this reset method inside cellForRowAtIndexPath immediately after you dequeue the cell from the queue.

Comment: I have added these to the subclassed cell:::::::::
func reset() {
        cellFileName.text = nil
        cellProgressView.progress = 0
        cellDownloadSpeed.text = nil
        cellBlock = {}
        
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        cellButton.hidden = false
        cellFinishIndicator.hidden = true
    }

after that in cellForIndexPath I added reset after dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

        cell.reset()

Still the same issue

Comment: I find this cellBlock approach strange it's kind of pointless..but ok.....Do you execute that block? You are setting it on the cell but that doesn't mean it is run.

Comment: On the contrary it is very useful. Yes it is running.

Comment: it works like this I add an -IBAction in the subclassed cell::::::: @IBAction func changeDownloadState(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        cellBlock()
        
    }

Comment: It's difficult to help when your original description doesn't really have a broader context which is how your product should actually behave from design perspective.

Comment: You mean I should share the whole xCode project ? I don't mind if it is necessary

Comment: A screenshot or a wireframe with expected UI behaviour would suffice..or one with pointed out what exactly is wrong..obviously you original post is not describing the issue clearly .because the answers we gave did not help so something else is an issue.